# D3: get the bounding box of a selected element

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, bounding-box

I have several elements in a svg and I want to zoom on one of them.

I'd like to do the same as [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9656675) but with non geo paths. Something like

```
d3.select(myElement).bounds() that I can use to pan and zoom my svg
```

I did not find anything with D3. did I miss something?

Thanks

Comment: What's a non geo path?

Comment: Something like this perhaps: `d3.select(myElement).node().getBoundingClientRect();`

Comment: to:RobertLongson. d3 defines geo path (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths). I want to get the bounding box for any svg namespace thing (g, rect, circle, path...)

Answer (score 13):

The Answer to the original question, and the implied general point is that yes, D3 has a function to access the underlying DOM node, and that no, it doesnt bother to override those functions where not necessary:

d3 has a function ".node()" which returns the the underlying DOM node of the *first* item in the d3 selection:

```
d3.select("#usefulSelector").node().getBBox();
```

for you specifically:

```
d3.select(myElement).node().getBBox()
```

docs:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#node

Answer (score 4):

You can call "getBBox()" on SVG elements to get their bounding box in terms of SVG coordinates.

```
var mousemove = function(d){
    var bbox = this.getBBox();
    ...
};

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("height", "100")
    .attr("width", "400");

var gPath = svg.append("g");


gPath.append("path")
    .attr("d", "M 250 10 L 320 10 L 350 50 L 290 65 z")
    .attr("fill", "steelblue")
    .on("mousemove", mousemove);
```

Once you have the bounding box, its a matter of deciding how specifically you want to actually transform the view to zoom into the bounding box. There are a bunch of different approaches so I'll leave that for you to investigate.

### Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/reblace/3rDPC/3/

Answer (score 0):

If yo're usign an SVG element (e.g. `<text>`), you can use `element.node().getBBox()` otherwise `.getBBox()` will not work. Use `element.node().getBoundingClientRect()` for normal html elements.

```js
console.log(d3.select('text').node().getBBox())
console.log(d3.select('div').node().getBoundingClientRect())
```

```css
.el {
  margin: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>

<div class="el"></div>
<svg><text>Text</text></svg>
```