# Programmatic zoom to node in force directed graph

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to implement a "zoom to node" behavior in a force directed graph in d3. The user should be able to click a link, which triggers a transition zooming to a specific node in the graph layout.

Normal zooming (e.g. with mouse/touch events) is working as expected, using the ["semantic" zoom](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680957) approach.

I tried setting the translate vector and scale programmatically and then manually triggering the zoom event, but i'm unsure how to calculate the translate vector, in order to center the specified node using it's x and y coordinates.

```
zoomToNode = (n) ->
  zoom.scale(4)                 # scaleExtent() = [1,10]
  # how do i calculate the translate vector here?
  zoom.event(vis)
```

Also i don't know, how to use this with a transition.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**Update:**

I still can't figure out, how to calculate the correct translate vector.. See [**this jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/gr0tttb2/6/). The translate vector is calculated in line 290. Note that the element is responsive, maybe that's causing some trouble..

Comment: possible duplicate of [D3: get the bounding box of a selected element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534988/d3-get-the-bounding-box-of-a-selected-element)

Comment: Thanks, the example shown there put me on the right track. However i still don't know how to calculate the translate vector, even though it should be simpler than in the given example, since i don't need to consider different bounding box sizes.